# How to show that the composition of two paths is contiuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let ($X,\tau$) be a topological space. Let $x,y,z \in X$.

Let $\alpha \in P_{(X,\tau)}(x,y)$ and $\beta \in P_{(X,\tau)}(y,z)$. How do I show that the meld $\alpha * \beta$ of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, defined as:

$\alpha * \beta (s) = \begin{cases}
       \alpha(2s) &s \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\\
       \beta(2s-1) &s \in [\frac{1}{2},1]\\
     \end{cases} $

is continuous? I know about the glue lemma but in order to apply this I have to show that $\alpha * \beta _{|[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$ and $\alpha * \beta _{|[\frac{1}{2},1]}$ are continuous. Even though I know $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are continuous and it seems "obvious" that this would make $\alpha * \beta _{|[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$ and $\alpha * \beta _{|[\frac{1}{2},1]}$ also continuous, but what is the exact  argument to show this?

Comment: The argument is, that composition of continuous functions, is continuous. As you said by the glueing lemma, you then need that the ends of your both paths take on the same value. Or to be more specific, $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(2s-1)$ are continuous functions, and the "glueing point" for $s=1/2$, is the same value, as $\alpha(1)=\beta(0)$.

Comment: But how do I show that $\alpha(2s)$ and $\beta(2s-1)$ are continuous?

Comment: As paths $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are continuous. And so are the functions $2s$ and $2s-1$. So you have composition of continuous functions.

Comment: $s\mapsto\alpha(2s)$ is a *composition* of two functions $s\mapsto 2s$ and $s\mapsto  \alpha(s)$. Both are continuous.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To close the question: define $h_1: [0,\frac12] \to [0,1]$ by $h_1(s)=2s$. It is clear that $h_1$ is continuous (even a homeomorphism).

Also define $h_2: [\frac12, 1] \to [0,1]$ by $h_2(s)=2s-1$. Also continuous and a homeomorphism. (both can be shown metrically by noting that $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ works uniformly, if you must; they also are increasing bijections so that's also a possible argument for the order topology).

Then note that $(\alpha \ast \beta)\restriction_{[0,\frac12]} = \alpha \circ h_1$ which is continuous as a composition of two continuous functions.

Same for $(\alpha \ast \beta)\restriction_{[\frac12,1]} = \beta \circ h_2$.

And as both $(\alpha \ast \beta)\restriction_{[0,\frac12]}(\frac12)= \alpha(1)=y$ and $(\alpha \ast \beta)\restriction_{[\frac12,1]}(\frac12)=\beta(0)=y$, they agree on the overlap $[0,\frac12] \cap [\frac12,1] = \{\frac12\}$ so the glueing lemma applies as both parts are closed in $[0,1]$.

That should be detailed enough. Of course in practice such things are never written out in such boring detail..

Comment: Why is it *boring detail*? It is likely an exercise (so this level of detail is necessary) and since op doesn’t seem to know how to prove it, it is hardly boring…

Comment: @PrudiiArca in a paper or most textbooks you won’t find it. Online maybe the first time it’s used in a text book.